# how can i create dylib with init function

Tags: xcode, dylib

I am trying to create a dylib in xcode. I can able to create dylb by choosing c/c++ Library template in Xcode.

I want to add "init" method for this dylib. I don't know how to add "init" method for dylib.

My idea is to call this "init" on runtime with the help of dlopen().

Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: Why do you call `init` a method? It is a function!

Answer (score 0):

If you code in C++, you could have static objects in your `dlopen`-ed library; their constructors get called at `dlopen` time (and their destructor is running at `dlclose` time).

If your code is compiled by `gcc` (be it in C, or in C++, or perhaps even some other languages) you could use the `constructor` and `destructor` [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

<sup>(You could use the obsolete symbols `_init` and `_fini` but this is an obsolete feature of `dlopen` (at least on Linux, and probably on MacOSX). Then you would have to declare them `extern "C" void _init(void);` in C++.)</sup>

Don't forget that `dlsym` deals with [unmangled names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), so you want to declare `extern "C"` the C++ names for it.

You could also have your own convention that your dynamically loaded things should have, for example, a function named `my_initialization` and your code doing the `dlopen` would later use `dlsym` to find it. You should have documented conventions on what symbols are `dlsym`-ed and how they are used.

I don't know well MacOSX, but I googled [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052i)

Comment: Thanks Basile Starynkevitch. I have create the "init" method. I can able to call it using "dlsym".

Comment: Why do you call that `init` a method?